# SQL/database for searching 1 billion times through a table of 30 million records

Tags: mysql, sql, nosql

I have ~30 million records consisting of strings of max 64 chars length
I have about billion of strings I would like to match with those 30 million.
If possible I'd want to do a substring match, if not an exact match.

I tried using mysql with proper indexes but the the time to search is very high, regardless to LIKE or = matches.

What is the best approach/database to make such a search  as fast as possible ?
In worst case I can try program something in C but I'd prefer a finished solution

**Update**
I think I found a possible solution, I'm adding CRC32 unsigned integer columns into the table. 
That will not allow a LIKE search but I can make an integer search based on the crc32 hash and then pick the right match out from possible duplicates.
I guess that will be the fastest way for exact match searches

Comment: did your program execute SQL 1 billion times? or did you try join 1 billion records table using like condition?

Comment: It's done sequentially.
I didn't even think about using JOIN probably that's the better method.

But joining 1 billion rows with 30 million (or even 100) would probably also be a massive problem. Right ?